# Robot Framework and testing windows GUI tool - select menu or other options and buttons

Tags: robotframework

We have a Windows 7 GUI tool just like MS Paint and need to test this application using Robot Framework.

Is there a possible way that we can select / execute different menu options by of the GUI tool - I have no code to share as I am not sure even how to implement it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `robotframework-autoitlibrary` it allows us to automate desktop application.

> AutoItLibrary is a Robot Framework keyword library wrapper for for the
>   freeware AutoIt tool,
>   using AutoIt's AutoItX.dll COM object. The AutoItLibrary class
>   provides a proxy for the AutoIt keywords callable on the AutoIt COM
>   object and provides additional high-level keywords implemented as
>   methods in this class.

This [link](https://github.com/HW71/AutoItLibrary/blob/master/doc/AutoItLibrary.html) contains all the information you need about keywords, how it works etc.

You could also write keywords in python and then use them in robot-framework for that you could use `pywinauto` library

Example code:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
def Open_And_Click:
  app = Application()
  app.start_("C:\\Temp\\setup.exe")
  mainWindow = app.SampleApplication
  mainWindow.Wait('ready')
  mainWindow['&Next'].ClickInput()
  mainWindow['&Next'].ClickInput()
  mainWindow['&Finish'].ClickInput()
  mainWindow.WaitNot('visible')
```

Comment: Thanks on a bit more search I found this library https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoIt/